# If Java is pass by value, how does this swap method work?

Tags: java

OK so I understand that Java is pass by value (including for References, it passes the Object by the VALUE of the reference - i.e. the address).

If so then why does the `swap(int[] array)` method - passing an array of primitives - work?

```
public class TestArraySwap {

    public static void swap(int a, int b) {
        int temp =b;
        b=a;
        a=temp;
    }

    public static void swap(int[]a) {
        int temp = a[1];
        a[1]=a[0];
        a[0]=temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test Primitive swap
        int a=1;
        int b=2;
        System.out.println("a="+a +" b="+b);
        swap(a,b);
        System.out.println("a="+a +" b="+b);

        //Test array swap
        int[] array = new int[2];
        array[0]=1;
        array[1]=2;
        System.out.println("a[0]="+array[0] +" a[1]="+array[1]);
        swap(array);
        System.out.println("a[0]="+array[0] +" a[1]="+array[1]);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
a=1 b=2
a=1 b=2
a[0]=1 a[1]=2
a[0]=2 a[1]=1
```

The second swap works - I would expect it not to but perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The second `swap`works because you're modifying the internal state of the array.

Comment: Why would you expect it not to work?

Comment: Because arrays are mutable, and primitives are not.

Comment: Give this guy a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference it is a goldmine of information!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - yes but it wasn't clear to me (previously) that an array was just an object - I thought it was just a "bunch" of primitives and would behave as such. Now I know an array is an Object :-)

Comment: @roippi, No.  Mutability has nothing to do with it.  It's because array variables are reference variables (which are passed by value to a method), whereas primitives are NOT reference variables.

Answer (score 3):

The main method has a reference to an array:

```
R1 ------> [1, 2]
```

Then it calls the `swap()` method. So a copy of the reference to the same array is created and used by the `swap()` method:

```
 R1 -----> [1, 2]
             ^
             |
 R2 ---------|
```

Then the `swap()` method changes the content of the array:

```
 R1 -----> [2, 1]
             ^
             |
 R2 ---------|
```

And it returns. R1 still references the same array, whose content has been changed.

Comment: I downvoted because the essence of the answer is that in Java arrays (even of primitives) are Objects. Once that was clear, the fact that it was an array of primitives (and primitives are passed by value) was irrelevant.

Comment: @kellyfj that's covered in the basics: [Java tutorial Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html): *An array is a container **object***. This answer explains this, the fact you didn't know it before posting the question doesn't mean you should downvote this answer.

Comment: If my answer doesn't make it clear that Java passes copies of references to arrays, then I really don't know how to make it clearer. It looks like you thought Java arrays were passed by value. My answer explains that it's not the case. References to the array are passed.

Answer (score 0):

The swap works because you pass the address (reference) of the array to the method.  The method then operates on that array -- the same one the other method has a reference to.

I really don't like the statement, "Java is pass by value."  I think it's really confusing.

---

```
 public void methodA(){
     int[] values = {1,2}; 
    // MethodA stack frame has a register that contains a 
    //   memory address (let's say it's 0x1F) that points to a contiguous section of 
    //   memory sized for an integerarray of size 2. 
     methodB(values); // Pass the **memory address** (aka REFERENCE) not the register address
     System.out.println(values[0]); // Prints "100"
 } 

 public void methodB(int[] ints){
     // MethodB stack frame now has a register with the memory address (0x1F)
     //    of 'ints' which is the same address that MethodA stack frame has.
     //    The same REFERENCE
     ints[0] = 100; // Alter the value in mem of 0x1F+0
     ints = new int[2]; // The local register overwrites the memory address of 
                        // the REFERENCE value that was there with 
                        // a new memory address -- say 0x5A
                        // since it's not storing it in the same register 
                        // as MethodA, MethodA will not reflect this.


 }
```

Comment: But Java **IS** pass by value.

Comment: I love being anal about this. _pass the address (reference)_ is wrong. It passes a copy of the value of the address.

Comment: Java **IS** pass by value for primitive types. Unless you consider passing an adress by value still a by value pass. Of course it's by value, but conceptually it's be reference.

Comment: No it isn't.  If it were, you could not do what he's accomplishing.  Are you, or are you NOT passing the reference value??  That's not the value of the object (i.e. a deep clone.)  I'm welcome to my opinion.  This is a semantic argument.

Comment: @HugoTunius is pass by value for object references as well.

Comment: If you think is not pass by value, just modify the `swap` method to exchange the values of two object references instead, test it and get your answer.

Comment: @Luiggi:  Nope.  The value of the object is not a reference.  The value of the object is what it's comprised of.

Comment: @Mad But the object isn't passed. The value of the reference is copied and that is passed.

Comment: Yes it is. If you still don't believe it, try following my suggestion on the last comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It would still be a pass by reference. In your example only the local copies of the adress would be modified and thus they wouldn't swap. It's still pass by reference because pass by value would mean that the whole objects get's deep copied.

Comment: @HugoTunius try it and see that it is not pass by reference :).

Comment: @Luiggi:  Are you saying my statement is wrong?  "The swap works because you pass the address (reference) of the array to the method. The method then operates on that array -- the same one the other method has a reference to." ??

Comment: Yes, your statement is wrong. Read the most voted answer to have a better understanding about what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: wow.  All of my debuggers must be giving me the wrong information then when I can see the **reference** address between two scope.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza We are arguing over the definition of pass by reference and pass by value. All I am saying is that objects in java are not deep copied when passed, I know that you will have local reference variables for them in the function.

Comment: No they're not, but you're not understanding the Java programming concepts.

Comment: @HugoTunius still, **it is not** pass by reference. **Never**.

Comment: If Java were pass by reference, then it would be possible to do `a = new int[] { a[1], a[0] }` inside the swap method. But it is not.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not pass by reference in the C++ sense, but it is pass by reference in the sense that the objects don't get copied. As I said it's a futile argument because we agree and it's really only a matter of terminology

Comment: @HugoTunius is pass by value. Period. No matter which language or idiom you use.

Comment: MadConan clearly states that the address is passed, and uses reference as a synonym. Sure, the latter is not exactly correct, but this whole exchange is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: If it wasn't confusing, this whole exchange wouldn't be happening.

Comment: The reference is not passed. A copy of the value of the reference is passed. That clears everything up.

Comment: True that it's really confusing because there are no references in Java and for me 'value' is something associated with stored in stack (i.e. `struct` in C), not an object placed in heap.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev: "There are no references in Java"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I always thought that this statement comes from C/C++ language. And their references are not Java's references as they allow modifying primitives. Anyway, it's always been confusing for me, so correct me if I'm wrong. I can also create a question on this confusion...

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found this answer
[Array seems to be getting passed by reference in Java, how is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892992/array-seems-to-be-getting-passed-by-reference-in-java-how-is-this-possible)

and of course the Java spec itself

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Java is passed by value (by copy).

`swap(int[] a)` works, because it passes (copies) only an **address** of the beginning of an array. Later it directly modifies memory **under that address** (`a[0]`) and the next one (`a[1]`).

`swap(int a, int b)` doesn't work, because it modifies copies of integers.

Answer (score 0):

References in Java are something pointing to an object in heap. Arrays in Java are always allocated in heap. So arrays in Java are like *normal objects*.

References to objects in Java are stored in stack like primitive variables (`int`, `long`), it's a memory address stored in variable. So when they say that objects are passed by value, the literal meaning is that you copy address value into method parameters.

And for me this has always been **confusing** because though I do understand the process, I can't recall how it's properly named as

- there are no references in Java
- I'm always stuck when I hear the word 'value' applied to an object