# Passing Reference changing the code in java

Tags: java

If java is Pass By value Only Than why here its changing the value in list

I tried with Object also

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(12);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(45);
    addExternally(list);

    ListIterator<Integer> 
    iterator = list.listIterator(); 
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println("Value is : "
                + iterator.next()); 
    }
}

private static void addExternally(List<Integer> list) {
     list.add(11);
     list.add(12);

}
```

it should not take the changes from addExternally method but its taking why

Comment: The value that is being passed is the value of the reference to the list. Reassigning `list` inside the method won't be visible on the outside but changing the list itself (i.e. the elements in the list) will be.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the reference passed to the method actually refers to the same object as the one referred in your main method.

For more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893009/6671004

If you want to make temporary changes to your list, you can use :

```
List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
```

or use

```
List<Integer> tempList = (ArrayList<Integer>) list.clone();
```

Comment: thanks got the reason

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped.