# System.arraycopy() shallow copy or deepcopy with primitive and object references

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I read somewhere that `System.arraycopy` does create a new copy for primitive data types and shallow copy for object references.

so, that I started the experiment that with below code

```
//trying with primitive values
int a[] ={1,2,3};
int b[] = new int[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0,a.length);
b[0] = 9;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
//now trying with object references
Object[] obj1 = {new Integer(3),new StringBuffer("hello")};
Object[] obj2 = new Object[obj1.length];
System.arraycopy(obj1,0,obj2,0,obj1.length);
obj1[1] = new StringBuffer("world");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj2));
```

and the output was

```
[1, 2, 3]
[9, 2, 3]
[3, world]
[3, hello]
```

But what I expected was

```
[1, 2, 3]
[9, 2, 3]
[3, world]
[3, world]
```

from the above  code, I understood that `System.arraycopy` does deep copy for object references
If so, how  `obj1[0] == obj2[0]` gives `true`

Comment: "Deep copy for primitives". How can you do a deep copy for primitives, when by definition, they do not refer to anything deeper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misconception.

Once you do

```
obj1[1] = new StringBuffer("world");
```

You have *replaced the reference* in `obj1[1]`. Now the two arrays contain different references to different objects.

If you want to see that what was copied was the actual reference, you should try instead:

```
obj1[1].setLength(3);
```

Now both `obj1[1]` and `obj2[1]` should contain the string `hel`, because you did not replace the reference but rather *changed the content*.

Answer (score 4):

`System.arraycopy` does shallow copy, which means it copies `Object` references when applied to non primitive arrays.

Therefore after `System.arraycopy(obj1,0,obj2,0,obj1.length);`, `obj1[0]==obj2[0]` and `obj1[1]==obj2[1]`, since both arrays hold references to the same `Object`s.

Once you assign a new value to `obj1[1]`, `obj1[1]` no longer refers to the same `StringBuffer` instance as `obj2[1]`. That's why the outputs of `Arrays.toString(obj1)` and `Arrays.toString(obj2)` are different.

If instead of

```
obj1[1] = new StringBuffer("world");
```

you would write

```
obj1[1].setLength(0);
obj1[1].append("world");
```

both print statements would output `[3, world]`, since both arrays would still refer to the same `StringBuffer` instance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's shallow copy for references.

First you create the reference to a `new StringBuffer("hello")`, then you make a shallow copy of that. So you've got 1 `StringBuffer`, but 2 references to it.

Finally you replace the other reference with a completely `new StringBuffer("world")`.

Comment: If so `obj1 == obj2` should give true right ? But it gives `false`

Comment: No, they're not references to the **same** array, so that returns false of course.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood that System.arraycopy does deep copy for object
>   references If so, how  obj1[0] == obj2[0] gives true

No, you are wrong, it doesn't perform the deep copy. Because **`obj1[0] == obj2[0]` refer the same integer objects (i.e., references stored in the arrays at index '0')** inside the both the arrays, so you are getting the answer as `true`. Also, you can compare `obj1[1] == obj2[1]` which returns `false`, because both the `StringBuffer` references are different.

Also, the other point is that `System.arrayCopy` does only a shallow copy (simply copies the references/values from one array to another), you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135104/system-arraycopy-copies-object-or-reference-to-object) on this.

Comment: `obj1[0] == obj2[0] compares the integer values` - actually that's wrong. `obj1[0]` and `obj2[0]` refer to the same `Integer` object as a result of the arraycopy statement, which is why `obj1[0] == obj2[0]`.  If you add a `obj2[0] = new Integer(3);` after the arraycopy statement, `obj1[0] == obj2[0] ` will no longer be true, even though both would still have the same value (3).