# java-- Why to copy arguments for Immunability of a Class?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, immutability

I've currently seen this constructor:

```
public ImmutableClass( final long id, final String[] arrayOfStrings,
    final Collection< String > collectionOfString) {

    this.id = id;
    this.arrayOfStrings = Arrays.copyOf( arrayOfStrings, arrayOfStrings.length );
    this.collectionOfString = new ArrayList<>( collectionOfString );
}
```

I have never seen something like that before. It was argued that it is for the "*Immutability*" of the Class and it makes sure that the state can't be modified from outside.

So, does this make sense or what is this?

Furthermore, I wanted to know why the arguments in this code are marked as final?

Comment: I think you mean `immutability`, not `immunability`, the latter which sounds like you are trying to make your code virus proof :-)

Comment: To achieve true immutability, it would be better to first deep-copy the list and then construct an immutable list (via [`Lists.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E...))) from the deep-copy list and assing this to `collectionsOfString`

Answer (score 3):

> So, does this make sense or what is this?

This will make a deep copy of String array argument.

```
arrayOfStrings = Arrays.copyOf( arrayOfStrings, arrayOfStrings.length );
```

This will copy the input array to inner variable, which effectively prevent modification `ImmutableClass.arrayOfStrings` field by modifying the supplied array.

If you simply assign it like this:

```
public ImmutableClass( final long id, final String[] input,
final Collection< String > collectionOfString) {

    this.id = id;
    this.arrayOfStrings = input;
...
}
```

Then when you modify the `input`: `input[0] = "new string"`, the inner `arrayOfStrings` got modified too, which breaks the `Immutable` characteristic

The same logic is applied to `collectionOfString`

> Furthermore, I wanted to know why the arguments in this code are marked as final?

It is a guard to prevent reassign supplied parameter to other value.

Comment: "*This will make a deep copy of input argument.*" - [No, it won't](https://ideone.com/IFU76W). Even implementing the broken `Cloneable` interface will not help in this case. You have to make the copies manually.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying. My point is the code doing a deep copy of input array to prevent modification from outside. What's conflicting with your point?

Comment: My code is. If I have any reference to any object that resides in the input array, I can mutate this object and these changes will be reflected in the copied version. `Arrays.copyOf(...)` does not create a deep copy.

Comment: But this is `String`. I did not say it applied to all object :D. I will make it more clear

Comment: You say is a deep copy, and this is false. `Arrays.copyOf(...)` only copies the references, not the objects.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` copy the input array String to a new array. It's a deep copy of that String array

Comment: If it were, then, [in the example I gave above](https://ideone.com/IFU76W), the change to `singleEntryInData` should not be reflected in `copy`.

Comment: Till now I don't know what you're talking about. For String/int/char array, it's deep copy. That method is backed by `System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length, newLength));`, it's not a simple reference copy

Comment: `System.arraycopy(...)` is implemented as native method call, there is no evidence that there is a "special version" of `System.arraycopy(...)` for `String`s or any other type, all reference-types are handled equally. The topic is also discussed and explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135104/system-arraycopy-copies-object-or-reference-to-object). `System.arraycopy(...)` and `Arrays.copyOf(...)` create shallow copies for reference-types.

Comment: String is immutable so it's effectively do a deep copy. For primitive type, it copies the values so deep copy too. You're right about the reference type, it's not a deep copy. Read my above comment please.