# How do I create a dictionary in java similar to the python dictionary and input multiple values at once?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

```
graph = {1:{'a','b'},2:{'c','d'},3:{'e','f'},4:{'g','h'},5:{'b','d'},6:{'b','e'},7:{'a','c'},8:{'f','h'},9:{'e','g'}}
```

What I have done:

```java
public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Character> universal = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(universal, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
        // System.out.println(universal);
        HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Character>> graph =
                new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Character>>();
        HashSet<Character> values = new HashSet<Character>();
        Collections.addAll(values, 'a', 'b');

        System.out.println(values);
        // Output : [a, b]

        graph.put(1, values);
        System.out.println(graph.get(1));
        // Output : [a, b]

        System.out.println(graph);
        // Output : {1=[a, b]}

        values.removeAll(values);
        System.out.println(graph.get(1));
        // Output : []

        // Why did the value clear out from the graph?
        System.out.println(graph);
        // Output : {1=[]}
    }
}
```

How do I put these values at once instead of using `put()` function all the time? Isn't there a better way? Also, explain the reason why `clear()` or `remove()` function usage on the variable *values* causes it to be removed from the variable *graph*. I want the structure to be mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python statement:

```python
graph = {1:{'a','b'},2:{'c','d'},3:{'e','f'},4:{'g','h'},5:{'b','d'},6:{'b','e'},7:{'a','c'},8:{'f','h'},9:{'e','g'}}
```

can be implemented in Java 9+ like this:

```java
graph = Map.of(1, Set.of("a", "b"),
               2, Set.of("c", "d"),
               3, Set.of("e", "f"),
               4, Set.of("g", "h"),
               5, Set.of("b", "d"),
               6, Set.of("b", "e"),
               7, Set.of("a", "c"),
               8, Set.of("f", "h"),
               9, Set.of("e", "g"));
```

The result is an *immutable* `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`, unlike Python, where the result is mutable.

Printed, it looks like this, where order changed because the `Map` is a `HashMap`:

```
{4=[g, h], 3=[e, f], 2=[c, d], 1=[a, b], 9=[e, g], 8=[f, h], 7=[a, c], 6=[b, e], 5=[b, d]}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that doesn't look like a python dictionary.  A python dictionary of dictionaries would be

```
{1: {'a': 'b'}, 2: {'c': 'd'}}
```

and a dictionary of tuples would be

```
{1: ('a', 'b'), 2: ('c', 'd')}
```

In Java, you *could* express than as a `Map<Integer, Map<Character, Character>>`, (or maybe a  `Map<Integer, List<Character>>` if that is what you mean) but that leads to non-idiomatic, cumbersome code.

Since your data structure is a map of contiguous integers, a better representation would be an array:

```
// Using Java 14 record types ...
public record Pair (char first, char second) {}

Pair[] theMapping = new Pair[]{
   null,
   new Pair('a', 'b'),
   new Pair('c', 'd'),
   // etc
};
```

The only gotcha is the `null` ... which is needed because Java array indexes start from zero.

This could also be expressed as a `char[][]` or in other ways that will be easier to use (and more efficient) than a `Map` of `Map` formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Java 9` you can implement it like this, result is *modifiable*:

```java
Map<Integer, Set<Character>> graph = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
        1, new HashSet<>(Set.of('a', 'b')),
        2, new HashSet<>(Set.of('c', 'd')),
        3, new HashSet<>(Set.of('e', 'f')),
        4, new HashSet<>(Set.of('g', 'h')),
        5, new HashSet<>(Set.of('b', 'd')),
        6, new HashSet<>(Set.of('b', 'e')),
        7, new HashSet<>(Set.of('a', 'c')),
        8, new HashSet<>(Set.of('f', 'h')),
        9, new HashSet<>(Set.of('e', 'g'))));
```

Shorter statement, but result is *unmodifiable*:

```java
Map<Integer, Set<Character>> immutable = Map.of(
        1, Set.of('a', 'b'),
        2, Set.of('c', 'd'),
        3, Set.of('e', 'f'),
        4, Set.of('g', 'h'),
        5, Set.of('b', 'd'),
        6, Set.of('b', 'e'),
        7, Set.of('a', 'c'),
        8, Set.of('f', 'h'),
        9, Set.of('e', 'g'));
```

---

In earlier versions, since `Java 1.5`, you can use statements like this, result is *modifiable*:

```java
Map<Integer, Set<Character>> graph = new HashMap();

graph.put(1, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('a', 'b')));
graph.put(2, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('c', 'd')));
graph.put(3, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('e', 'f')));
graph.put(4, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('g', 'h')));
graph.put(5, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('b', 'd')));
graph.put(6, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('b', 'e')));
graph.put(7, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('a', 'c')));
graph.put(8, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('f', 'h')));
graph.put(9, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('e', 'g')));
```

Shorter statements, result is also *modifiable*:

```java
Map<Integer, Set<Character>> graph = new HashMap() {{
    put(1, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('a', 'b')));
    put(2, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('c', 'd')));
    put(3, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('e', 'f')));
    put(4, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('g', 'h')));
    put(5, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('b', 'd')));
    put(6, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('b', 'e')));
    put(7, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('a', 'c')));
    put(8, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('f', 'h')));
    put(9, new HashSet(Arrays.asList('e', 'g')));
}};
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [System.arrayCopy() copies object or reference to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527436/14838237)

• [Invert a Map with redundant values to produce a multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540984/14838237)</sup>