# Changes in the copy of a 2-D array produced via Arrays.copyOf() reflect in the the original array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy, deep-copy

If I create a 2D `int` array in Java, and then make a copy of it using `Arrays.copyOf()`, like so -

```
jshell> int[][] c1 = {{1,2}, {3,4}}
c1 ==> int[2][] { int[2] { 1, 2 }, int[2] { 3, 4 } }

jshell> int[][] d1 = Arrays.copyOf(c1, c1.length)
d1 ==> int[2][] { int[2] { 1, 2 }, int[2] { 3, 4 } }
```

If I then change an element in the copy, why does the corresponding cell in the original 2D array get mutated in the process?

```
jshell> d1[0][0] = 0
$21 ==> 0

jshell> d1
d1 ==> int[2][] { int[2] { 0, 2 }, int[2] { 3, 4 } }

jshell> c1
c1 ==> int[2][] { int[2] { 0, 2 }, int[2] { 3, 4 } } // c1[0][0] was 1 originally
```

This leads me to believe that during a copy of 2D arrays using `Arrays.copyOf()`, a separate copy is created only for the outermost array, while each inner array is still a reference to the inner arrays of the original 2D array?

```
jshell> d1 = null
d1 ==> null

jshell> c1
c1 ==> int[2][] { int[2] { 0, 2 }, int[2] { 3, 4 } }
```

If so, why is it this way? Shouldn't `Arrays.copyOf()` create distinct copies, at least per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)? Is this behavior documented anywhere in the Oracle docs?

Lastly, what is the correct way to create distinct copies of a 2D array, the same way `Arrays.copyOf()` works for 1D arrays?

Answer (score 2):

A 2D array is basically an array that contains arrays, and `Arrays.copyOf` does a shallow copy, so only the outer array (the array of arrays) is copied, not the values inside the array (in this case, arrays of `int`, ie `int[]`). As a result, both the original and the copy contain the same `int[]` arrays, so if you modify through one, the result is also visible through the other.

This is explicitly mentioned in the javadoc:

> For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the
> copy, the two arrays will contain identical values.

You do need to read that with the knowledge of the signature: `<T> T[] copyOf(T[], int)`. The array copied is `T[]` (an array of `T`, where `T` is `int[]`), not `T[][]`!

For a deep copy of a 2D array, you will have to deep copy the array yourself, for example see [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Method [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,%20int)) does not perform a *deep copy* of an array, nor does [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method. You should implement the algorithm of *deep copy* of the array yourself with the required copy depth. For example:

```java
int[][] arr1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};                 // original array
int[][] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length); // shallow copy
int[][] arr3 = Arrays.stream(arr1)               // deep copy
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        .map(IntStream::toArray)
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

arr1[0][0] = 7;

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr1)); // [[7, 2], [3, 4]]
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2)); // [[7, 2], [3, 4]]
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr3)); // [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And the same is true for an array of objects:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeObject[] arr1 = {                                 // original array
                new SomeObject(1),
                new SomeObject(2),
                new SomeObject(3),
                new SomeObject(4)};
        SomeObject[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length); // shallow copy
        SomeObject[] arr3 = Arrays.stream(arr1)               // deep copy
                .mapToInt(SomeObject::getField)
                .mapToObj(SomeObject::new)
                .toArray(SomeObject[]::new);

        arr1[0].setField(7);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [7, 2, 3, 4]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [7, 2, 3, 4]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }

    static class SomeObject {
        int field;

        public SomeObject(int field) { this.field = field; }

        public int getField() { return field; }

        public void setField(int field) { this.field = field; }

        public String toString() { return String.valueOf(field); }
    }
}
```