# Why is my current object modified when I use an instance method to return another object? - Java

Tags: java, object, instance

I have this class and I don't understand what exactly is going on:

```
public class Table {
    private int[][] array;
    private int N;

    // constructor
    public Table(int[][] array) {
        N = array.length;
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, N);
    }

    // this method returns another Table object
    public Table tweak() {
        int[][] tweak = Arrays.copyOf(array, N);
        // here I change the array
        return new Table(tweak);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call the tweak method, the object used to call the method changes also:

```
public class TestCls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {{1, 2}, 
                         {3, 4}};
        Table a = new Table(array);
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        /* this will print
        *  1  2 
        *  3  4
        */

        Table b = a.tweak();
        System.out.println(b.toString());
        /* this will print
        *  2  1 
        *  3  4
        */

        System.out.println(a.toString());
        /* this will also print
        *  2  1 
        *  3  4
        */
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why is this happening and how should I change the tweak method so that the original object is not changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf` is creating a new `int[][]`, but that takes a *shallow* copy - it's equivalent to:

```
int[][] tweak = new int[array.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < tweak.length; i++) {
    tweak[i] = array[i];
}
```

So while you've got a new "top level" array, each "subarray" is shared. You really want to make a *deep* copy of the array:

```
int[][] tweak = new int[array.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < tweak.length; i++) {
    tweak[i] = array[i].clone(); // Simpler way of performing a shallow copy
}
```

That's performing a shallow copy of each "subarray", but that's fine because the element type is just `int` (there's no way to make it "deeper").

Note that you only need to this *either* in the `tweak` method *or* in the constructor. There's no point in making two copies.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the `Table` constructor makes a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) of the array.

See [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)