# Making copies of Objects in Java

Tags: java

I have this Java code:

```
boolean[][] defaultBoard = {{false, false, false},
                            {false, false, false},
                            {false, false, false}};
Board board = new Board(defaultBoard);
Board nextBoard = new Board(defaultBoard);
nextBoard.getBoard()[1][5] = true;
board.printBoard();
```

`printBoard`:

```
public void printBoard() {
    for (boolean row[] : board) {
        for (boolean cell : row) {
            System.out.print( cell ? "#" : "." );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But it returns

```
...
.#.
...
```

Which makes me think that `nextBoard` and `board` have got the same memory address. My question is: How do create a copy of `nextBoard` so that when `nextBoard` is edited, `board` isn't edited as well?

Comment: you can achieve the same thing with a `short` and bitwise operations.

Comment: `defaultBoard.clone()`.  (But then you need to clone each row as well.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564856/20394

Comment: If you have a 3 x 3 board how are you updating the 6th element i.e. `[5]` accessed the sixth element.

Answer (score 4):

It's not `board` and `nextBoard` that are the same. It is the `defaultBoard` array you are passing to the constructor. You need to pass different arrays. Otherwise, you are just modifying the same array.

Better yet, to ensure instances of `Board` always contain a new array, I would recommend doing a deep copy of the array inside the constructor.

Comment: if `Board`'s constructor made a defensive copy of its input, then it would be harder to write a misbehaving client.

Answer (score 0):

An array is an object, so you will pass a reference to the `Board` constructor. Since you are using the same array, both `board` and `nextBoard` are sharing the same object. To avoid this situation, use the `clone` method. This way, you will have a copy of the `defaultBoard` array and every instance you have their own board. It will look like this:

```
Board board = new Board(cloneBoard(defaultBoard));
Board nextBoard = new Board(cloneBoard(defaultBoard));

private boolean[][] cloneBoard(boolean[][] boardToClone) {
    boolean[][] clone = new boolean[boardToClone.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < boardToClone.length; i++) {
        clone[i] = boardToClone[i].clone();
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: clone doesn't perform a deep copy... meaning lines are referring to the same array, this wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: The method `cloneBoard` goes through every line an make a clone, so it is supposed to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method, present in any Java Object subclass, namely, all of them, far as I can tell.

Comment: clone doesn't perform a deep copy... meaning lines are referring to the same array, this wouldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would have the board create the array base don a size

```
class Board {
    final boolean[] board;

    public Board(int width, height) {
        board = new[width][height];
    }

    public boolean[][] getBoard() { return board; }

    public void set(int x, int y, boolean value) { board[x][y] = value; }
}
```

Now your code looks like this

```
Board board = new Board(3, 3);
Board nextBoard = new Board(3, 3);
nextBoard.set(1, 2, true); // the last element is 2 not 5
board.printBoard();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new fresh array every time you need to pass it to object so that the object's see a new array rather then the same array .