# How to make a new array from an old array?

Tags: java

```
float[][] pesIAlcada = {
        { 2.4f, 3.1f, 3.07f, 3.7f, 2.7f, 2.9f, 3.2f, 3f, 3.6f, 3.1f },
        { 19f, 18.7f, 22f, 24f, 17f, 18.5f, 21f, 20f, 18.7f, 22f, 18f },
        { 47f, 48f, 49f, 50f, 51f, 52f, 51.5f, 50.5f, 49.5f, 49.1f, 50f },
        { 101f, 104f, 106f, 107f, 107.5f, 108f, 109f, 110f, 112f, 103f } };
/* 
 * I already created an array. And I want to make a new one but some
 * infomation from the old array. How can I do, plz?
 */
float[][] pesNeixement = new float[ROWS][COLS];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < pesIAlcada[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(pesIAlcada[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you avoid using `float`  not only does it make examples like this more complicated, but it has much less precision (it is one billion times less accurate)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to deep-copy a 2d array.

```
public static float[][] deepCopy(float[][] original, Integer offset, Integer numberOfRows) {
    if (original == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (offset == null) {
        offset = 0;
    };

    if (numberOfRows == null) {
        numberOfRows = original.length;
    };

    final float[][] result = new float[numberOfRows - offset][];
    for (int i = offset; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
         result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(original[i], original[i].length);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And in your code:

```
float[][] pesNeixement = deepCopy(pesIAlcada, 0, 2);
```

Comment: I want to make a new Array called pesNeixement

and take just these two rows for the new array(pesNeixement) ..

{ {2.4f, 3.1f, 3.07f, 3.7f, 2.7f, 2.9f, 3.2f, 3f, 3.6f, 3.1f}, 
      {19f, 18.7f, 22f, 24f,17f, 18.5f, 21f, 20f, 18.7f, 22f, 18f},

Comment: You might want to add an extra `offset` argument, in case someone wants to copy *x* rows starting at row *y*.

Comment: @alex23 the code is identical to this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564856/951448

And this answer is 3 years older than the question you're referring to ...

Comment: @ alex23 Sorry I'm new here, how can I?

Answer (score 0):

It depends by your definition of "some information". If you want to copy a section of the array to a new one, then you can use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

**Example**

```
int[] numbers = {4,5,6,7,8};
int[] newNumbers = new int[10];

System.arraycopy(numbers,0,newNumbers,0,3);
```

Comment: I want to make a new Array called pesNeixement and take just these two rows for the new array(pesNeixement) ..


 { {2.4f, 3.1f, 3.07f, 3.7f, 2.7f, 2.9f, 3.2f, 3f, 3.6f, 3.1f}, {19f, 18.7f, 22f, 24f,17f, 18.5f, 21f, 20f, 18.7f, 22f, 18f},

Comment: So apply some reasoning, look at the answers you've been given and work out how you might get the top two lines.

Comment: Yes, i did here 

float[][] pesNeixement = new float[ROWS][COLS];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < pesIAlcada[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(pesIAlcada[i][j]);
    }
}


The problem is that how can i change the name from pesIAlcada to pesNeixement ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy some rows from `pesIAlcada` in an new array (`pesNeixement`) you can use something like this:

```
int fromRow = 0;     // Start copying at row0 (1st row)
int toRow = 2;       // Copy until row2 (3rd row) <- not included
                     // This will copy rows 0 and 1 (first two rows)
float[][] pesNeixement = new float[toRow - fromRow][];

for (int i = fromRow; i < toRow; i++) {
    pesNeixement[i] = new float[pesIAlcada[i].length];
    System.arraycopy(pesIAlcada[i], 0, pesNeixement[i], 0, pesIAlcada[i].length);               
}
```

Also see this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/Nj1v4y)**.

Answer (score 0):

`System.arrayCopy()` is the efficient way of creating new array from an existing array. What you can do with your own coding can be done using this also. Just explore