# printing a two dimensional matrix (array) java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print this in the correct two dimensional array format. SOmething is wrong. Need the print from the method. My output is what seems to be an infinite loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the dimension of your matrix?");
    int matrixdim = input.nextInt();
    double[][] matrix = new double[matrixdim][matrixdim];

    System.out.println("Enter " + matrixdim + " rows, and " + matrixdim + " columns." );
    Scanner input1= new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++)
            matrix[row][column] = input1.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Your original array:");

    System.out.println(printArray(matrix));
}   
public static double printArray(double matrix[][]){
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length;column++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[row][column] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
return printArray(matrix);
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you run the code?

Comment: If you are having an infinite loop, you must be missing a `}`...Check for the `{}` consistency. If you are using some IDE, like Eclipse, just right click on the mouse --> Source --> Format. This should help you with correct indentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I told you in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110399/1393766) invoking same method again `return printArray(matrix);` at the end of your method can lead to invoking it again (and again) until StackOverflow error.

Change return type to `void`. Now your method can look like

```
public static void printArray(double matrix[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or even better

```
public static void printArray(double matrix[][]) {
    for (double[] row : matrix) 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `println` to `print` in the first print call.

```
public static void printArray(double matrix[][]){
    for (...) {
        for (...) {
            //here just print goes
            System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        //at the end each row of the matrix you want the new line - println is good here
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

`print` does not print the newline (`\n`) at the end of the output, whereas the `println` does. That's why you're getting the ugly print.

Also, `printArray` should not return a value, it should be:

```
public static void printArray(double[][] matrix)
```

I think that's where you're getting your infinite loop. Don't return anything - no need, you are just printing it.

Comment: @jahroy Because it's a recursive call. Every time method tries to return a value it calls itself again. Try this method: `public int someMethod(int i) { return someMethod(i); }` and call it wherever from.

Comment: Yes... I understand that.  I mis-read the code at first due to its poor formatting and the missing `}`.  That said, the return type doesn't cause the infinite loop... it's the fact that the method invokes itself.  I have removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a } and use `print` instead of `println` inside your 2nd loop.

```
public static double printArray(double matrix[][])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) 
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length;column++) 
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you got `System.out.println(printArray(matrix));` instead of `printArray(matrix);` since your method got print calls in it anyway

and as mentioned above - `print` vs `println`