# Arrays.copyOf not returning deep Copy of objects

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I have function to deep copy a board of squares:

```
public Square[][] copy_array(Square[][] board) {

    Square[][] nv = new Square[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < nv.length; i++)
        nv[i] = Arrays.copyOf(board[i], board[i].length);

    return nv;
}
```

when I use this function and make changes to `nv`, it makes a change to the original `board[][] square` that I pass in. I read that `Arrays.copyOf` returns a cloned array that is unaffected by changes to the original. but this does not work the other way round, like the example above. the memory reference in source array is just pointed to the new location as per:  [Does Arrays.copyOf produce a shallow or a deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351726/does-arrays-copyof-produce-a-shallow-or-a-deep-copy)

what would be the best way to do a true deep copy so that changes to the objects in  `nv` do not change the objects in `board`?

Comment: Look at options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: that is javascript, son of arathorn, i require java!

Comment: Oh, where's my coffee this morning lol

Comment: If you need copies of each of your `Square` instances, then you should provide some way of copying them in the `Square` class, such as a copy constructor.

Comment: @entercaspa, are the objects serializable? you could use JAXB or something like that to serialize and de-serialize the array

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this

```
public Square[][] copy_array(Square[][] board) {

    Square[][] nv = new Square[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < nv.length; i++)
        nv[i] = board[i].clone();

    return nv;
}
```

I didn't test it but clone makes a deep copy