Why the method "Arrays.copyOf()" produces a defensive copy (instead of a shallow copy) when it is used on a getter?
I'm a beginner in Java programming. I am a bit confused about the result of the method "Arrays.copyOf()" when it is used on a getter.
I know that this method usually produce a shallow copy of the argument passed to it. However, it seems that when it is used on a getter to implement a defensive copy of an array, the result returned by the getter is not a shallow copy. (see similar article:
https://github.com/albertattard/what-is-defensive-copying)
Could you please explain me why the method ""Arrays.copyOf()" doesn't return a shallow copy when it used in a getter to return a copy of an array?
PersonRecord class
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PersonRecord{
    private final String name;
    private final String dob;
    private final PersonRecord[] kids;
    
    //CONSTRUCTOR
      public PersonRecord(String name, String dob, PersonRecord[] kids) {
          this.name = name;
          this.dob = dob;
          this.kids = kids;
      }
    
    //GETTER for the field "kids"
    //Use a DEFENSIVE copy for my 3rd field
    public PersonRecord[] getKids() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(kids, kids.length);
    }
    
    //"toString()" METHOD (this method only prints the content of the field "kids")
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String kidString = "n/a";
        String[] names = new String[kids.length];
        Arrays.setAll(names, i -> names[i] = kids[i].name);
        kidString = String.join(",", names);
        return kidString;
   }
}

}

My goal is to instantiate a record "john" of type "PersonRecord". Its third field should be the array "johnKids"
    //Create content of my 3rd field "johnKids"
    PersonRecord jane = new PersonRecord("Jane", "01/01/1930", null);
    PersonRecord jim = new PersonRecord("Jim", "02/02/1932", null);
    PersonRecord joe = new PersonRecord("Joe", "03/03/1934", null);

    //Create array for my 3rd field
    PersonRecord[] johnsKids = {jane, jim, joe}; 
    
    //Create an instance of my class named "john"
    PersonRecord john = new PersonRecord("John", "05/05/1900", johnsKids);

    //Print my object john
    System.out.println(john); 
    //RESULT : 3rd field => {Jane, Jim, Joe}

    //Assign the result of a call the my getter of the 3rd field to a new array
    PersonRecord[] newArray = john.getKids();

    //Make some modifications on the new array
    newArray[0] = jim;
    newArray[1] = new PersonRecord("Ann", "04/04/1936", null);
    
    //Print my object john
    System.out.println(john); 
    //RESULT (not modified) : 3rd field => {Jane, Jim, Joe}
    

This result proves that "newArray" and the field "kids" are referencing different objects in memory. I'm confused because in the return type of the getter method ("getKids()"), it's the "Arrays.copyOf()" which was used, and this means that the returned copy was supposed to be a shallow copy (i.e. a copy of the reference in the field "kids", and not a copy of the object behind the field "kids"). If "Arrays.copyOf()" is supposed to return a shallow copy, why the modification made on "newArray" didn't reflect on my third field "kids"?

All your code does is prove that the Arrays.copyOf() method returns a shallow copy.

@RobbyCornelissen can you elaborate on this a little more? It seems to prove that Arrays.copyOf returns a deep copy to me.

@AndrewYim you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351779/16034206

@BIBOOunit Seems I need to go back to basics. Thanks.

For newArray and kids to reference the same object you must not make a copy - you would need to use the assignment operator (i.e. newArray = kids;)

a shallow copy means getting a new array (a copy) but with the same content. A deep copy would be a new array with a (deep) copy of each of its element. So you must change an attribute of one of its element to see if it is a shallow copy or not (e.g. newArray[0].setName(...) or newArray[0].addKid(...) - both not possible with posted code) and compare with the corresponding element of the original array.

That's because you misunderstand what a shallow copy is. Here is some source code of what is underlying the Arrays.copyOf() method:
public static <T> T[] copyOf(T[] original, int newLength) {
    return copyOf(original, newLength, original.getClass());
}

@IntrinsicCandidate
public static <T, U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    T[] copy = newType == Object[].class ? new Object[newLength] : (Object[])Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}

The two arrays are different arrays - meaning that changes to kids will not be reflected to newArray and vice versa. So when you change what the index 1 is pointing to, that is changing the reference stored in the array. You are not modifying the object that the reference points to.
However, the elements in the array are shallow copies - meaning that if you modify any one of the objects in kids or newArray using a setter, the changes will be reflected to the other array.

Thank you very much. Your answer implies that the efficiency of the DEFENSIVE copy mechanism implemented on the GETTER is ALSO due to the fact that the field "kids" is PRIVATE and has no SETTER.

wait, what???? what does this have to do with efficiency?? Its a setter for the object PersonRecord not the array.

What I am saying is that the efficiency of the DEFENSIVE copy mechanism implemented on the GETTER is ALSO due to the fact that the field "kids" is PRIVATE and has no SETTER. In other words, it's impossible to  MODIFY  the REFERENCE in the field , after the initialisation of its object.

This is still a shallow copy. A shallow copy is copy of an array that does not clone its parent's elements. In this case, that means johnsKids[0] points to the PersonRecord object as newArray[0] instead of pointing to a new PersonRecord with the same values.
This does not mean that modifications to the copy will apply to the original, only that modifying individual elements will. If you defined a PersonRecord.setName setter method, you would see this in action:
newArray[0].setName("Jean");
System.out.println(john);

Since you're modifying an element in the array, not the array itself, the changes are reflected in the original array.
Your sample, in contrast, modified the array directly. This change would not be reflected in the original because the two arrays do not represent the same object - they just happened to contain the same elements at a certain point in time.
