# Why is this Array getting modified?

Tags: java, algorithm, clone, backtracking, maze

I have an array called `maze` which in, theory, should get modified only in the `updateMaze()` method. This is because that is the final result I want to output to the console. The problem is when `tempMaze` gets modified `maze` is modified as well. This is not supposed to happen. My first thought was that they are pointing to same reference in memory however I checked and that is false. I do have to mention I used `clone()` at initialization to make their contents similar, and I am not sure if this could be a issue or not. (Even though I think I understand what `clone()` does I am not familiar enough to know if it is the problem or not.) My code:

```
public class ThreadTheMaze {
    ArrayList<Cell> result = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    private String[][] maze;
    private String[][] tempMaze;

    private int initRowPosition;
    private int initColPosition;

    private int amtOfRows;
    private int amtOfCols;

    public ThreadTheMaze(int initRow, int initCol){
        initRowPosition = initRow;
        initColPosition = initCol;
        result.add(new Cell(initRowPosition, initColPosition));
    }

    public void loadMaze(){
        try{
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("mazeData.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextLine()){
                amtOfCols = in.nextLine().length();
                amtOfRows++;
            }
            in.close();

            maze = new String[amtOfRows][amtOfCols];

            in = new Scanner(new File("mazeData.txt"));
            for (int r = 0; r < amtOfRows; r++){
                String line = in.nextLine();
                for (int c = 0; c < amtOfCols; c++){
                    maze[r][c] = line.substring(0,1);
                    line = line.substring(1);
                }
            }
            tempMaze = maze.clone();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.print(e);
        }
    }

    public void printMaze(){
        for (int r = 0; r < amtOfRows; r++){
            for (int c = 0; c < amtOfCols; c++){
                System.out.print(maze[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void updateMaze(){
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
            maze[result.get(i).getRow()][result.get(i).getColumn()] = "!";
        }
    }

    /**
     @return ArrayList of objects 'Cell' that are the solution to the maze. (Note: if no solution then returns empty ArrayList)
    */


    public void solve(Cell cell){
        tempMaze[cell.getRow()][cell.getColumn()] = "!";
        ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = getNeighbors(cell);

        if ((cell.getRow() == 0 || cell.getRow() == tempMaze.length-1) || (cell.getColumn() == 0 || cell.getColumn() == tempMaze[0].length-1)){
            return;
        }

        if ((cell.getColumn() == initColPosition && cell.getRow() == initRowPosition) && neighbors.size() < 1){
            return;
        }

        // If not in init position and has no neighbors then backtrack
        if ((cell.getColumn() != initColPosition || cell.getRow() != initRowPosition) && neighbors.size() < 1){
            result.remove(result.size()-1);
            solve(result.get(result.size()-1));
        }else if (neighbors.size() >= 1){ // If has neighbors then choose one and call the method again
            result.add(neighbors.get(0));
            solve(neighbors.get(0));
        }
    }

    /**
     @return ArrayList of objects 'Cell' that are empty and available to move to.
    */

    private ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbors(Cell cell){
        ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        int row = cell.getRow();
        int column = cell.getColumn();
        int[][] moveLocs = {{row-1, column}, {row+1, column}, {row, column+1}, {row, column-1}};
        for (int r = 0; r < moveLocs.length; r++){
            int tRow = moveLocs[r][0];
            int tCol = moveLocs[r][1];
            if (isValid(tRow, tCol)){
                Cell neighbor = new Cell(tRow, tCol);
                neighbors.add(neighbor);
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    public boolean isValid(int row, int col){
        if(row < 0 || row >= amtOfRows){
            return false;
        }
        if (col < 0 || col >= amtOfCols){
            return false;
        }
        if (!tempMaze[row][col].equals(" ")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The class `Cell` is a simple class with some simple get and set method.

I know this isn't the most concise way to present you my question, but really I can't spot a place were the problem could exist. Thanks.

Comment: @amit It's a built-in method for arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`clone()` is shallow.** This means that the following:

```
        tempMaze = maze.clone();
```

only clones the first level of the 2D array. In other words, you get a new array *containing the same `String[]` references as the original array*.

For suggestions on how to fix this, see [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)