# Can anyone tell how to assign the static string array to normal string array in java

Tags: java

i have tried to assign directly and by creating new instance also.
it is assigning values fine.but if i try to modify the normal string array,static string array is also modifying.can anyone help on this

Comment: Can you share your code, please?

Comment: defensive copy. create a new array with the same values, instead of a shared reference.

Comment: i think a deep copy will help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Arrays.copyOf` which not only copy elements, but also creates a new array.
See the below code, it solves your problem:-

```
 static  String[] array=new String[]{"1","2"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array2=Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
       System.out.println("Printing array2:-");
        for(String elem:array2){
            System.out.print(elem+"|");
        }
        System.out.println("\nPrinting array:-");
        array[0]="4";
        for(String elem:array){
            System.out.print(elem+"|");
        }
        System.out.println("\nPrinting array2:-");
        for(String elem:array2){
            System.out.print(elem+"|");
        }
    }

Output:-

Printing array2:-
1|2|
Printing array:-
4|2|
Printing array2:-
1|2|
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new string array, it wont share the reference.

Example with `String`:

```
String s1 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s2 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s3 = s1;                   // same reference
String s4 = new String("Hello");  // String object
String s5 = new String("Hello");  // String object
```

[image]

More info: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html