# Does Constructor effectively make a copy of a Referenced Parameter?

Tags: java

I need to copy a multi-dimensional array and put the copies in new objects. The original array will still be in use.

```
{...
     thisConstructor (myValuableArray)  ....}   // calling constructor

public thisConstructor (int[][] argArray) {

  int[][] hopefullyCopy = argArray;
}
```

is `myValuableArray` safe?

I understand Java passes parameters by value but I am not clear on the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe from mutations applied outside the class.

You will need to take a deep copy of the array in your constructor to do that. See [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the help; Issue is clear now