# Assign a matrix to another matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

While I was working on some Java code, I figured that there might be something different between these 2 codes.
I know that they have the same functionality, but I think there is something different between them under the hood.

This is the first code:

```
int[][] MainMatrix = new int[2][2];
int[][] A = new int[2][2];
MainMatrix[0][0]=100;
MainMatrix[0][1]=200;
MainMatrix[1][0]=300;
MainMatrix[1][1]=400;


A=MainMatrix;
```

And this is the second one:

```
int[][] MainMatrix = new int[2][2];
int[][] A = new int[2][2];
MainMatrix[0][0]=100;
MainMatrix[0][1]=200;
MainMatrix[1][0]=300;
MainMatrix[1][1]=400;


for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        A[i][j]=MainMatrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

So, what's the difference?

Comment: If you want to "copy" a 2D array, refer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Comment: If you want to write Java code that looks like Java (and not like C#), you should name your variables `mainMatrix` and `a` (starting with a lowercase letter).

Comment: Why?is that a syntax or something?

Comment: Not syntax, Java naming conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that they have the same functionality

Not quite...

The second example you have two distinct objects containing the same values . Updates to one are not reflected in the other.

The first example, you have only **one** matrix (at least after `A=MainMatrix;`), and two *references*. Any updates to `A` will be reflected in `MainMatrix` (and vice-versa).

Comment: Thank you so much.That is exactly what I was feeling.each time I was changing a matrix I felt every matrices were changing  as well.because I was using the first strategy but as I used The second strategy every thing went fine.

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian If you have found an answer to the question then please mark the answer as the "correct answer".

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, `A` and `MainMatrix` both end up referring to the same array in memory.  In the second snippet, you end up with two different arrays that contain the same values.

Answer (score 0):

The diffrence is, the first is refrencing `A` to `MainMatrix`, meaning `A` and `MainMatrix` refer to the same `int[][]`. if you modify `MainMatrix`, `A` is changed as well cause they point to the same location in memory.

your second way is copying `MainMatrix` to `A`, both a seperate and if you change one the other stays unchaged cause they point to diffrent locations in memory.