# how to compare duplicated arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Recently, I figured you can duplicate a array like this

```
System.arraycopy(src,0,dup,0,src.length);
```

However, even though the two arrays are the same, when you compare them using

```
if(src==dup)
   ...//print true
else if(src!=dup)
   ...//print false
```

It would always print false. Are there anyways to duplicate an array that does not change with the original one while also being able to compare those two correctly?

Comment: You are looking for "deep copy". There are a few questions that might be related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as amahfouz stated in his answer, the references of two different arrays are compared (in the way you wrote in your post).

So, to be able to compare the elements, you should loop through them.

You can **import Java.util.Arrays**, and do this:

```
if(Arrays.equals(src, dup))
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

Answer (score 0):

The equality test just compares references, not content, so it will always return false for two different array references.

Comment: Do I use a for loop to compare src[x] to dup[x] then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
Arrays.equals()
```