# Pass by value. Array

Tags: kotlin

I have two arrays. But when I change second - first change too.
I tried 
*.clone()
.copyOf()* 
but it didn't work for me.

```
object MatrixObject {
 var table: Array<Array<Int>>? = null

 fun randOf(n: Int) {
    table= Array(n, { Array(n, { Random().nextInt(100 - 0) + 0 }) })
 }

 var tableF: Array<Array<Int>>? = null
    get() {
        if (field==null)
          factorization()
        return field
    }

 fun factorization() {
        tableF = table!! 
        ...     //here I change elements of tableF
  }


}
```

I tried

```
 for(row in 0 until table!!.size)
   tableF!![row] = Arrays.copyOf(table!![row], table!![row].size)
```

and

```
 for(row in 0 until table!!.size)
   tableF!![row] = table!![row].clone() // and copyOf()
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.I initialized the array.

```
        tableF= Array(table!!.size, { Array(table!!.size, {0}) })
        for(row in 0 until table!!.size)
            tableF!![row] = table!![row].clone()
```