# Array as attribute in an object

Tags: java, arrays, class, reference, attributes

I'm relatively new to Java, and I just learned this

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {

  private int[][] foo;

  public Foo(int[][] arr) {
    this.foo = arr;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return Arrays.deepToString(this.foo).replace("],", "],\n");
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[][] p = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
    
    Foo g = new Foo(p.clone()); // doesn't work with p nor p.clone()
    System.out.println(g);
    
    p[0][0] = 1;
    
    System.out.println(g);
    
  }

}
```

Here I create an object with a reference to another object, and I can alter the object from the outside since I have the reference to the thing I just passed as an argument to the constructor.

This, although I understand why it happens, seems counterintuitive to me. If I save  something as an attribute of an object I expect the object to have a “private” copy  not accessible outside.

And I tried with `.clone()` and doesn't solve it. So the question is...

How is this usually done? Do I need to write a few `for` loops inside the constructor to get every value out of the argument?

### (Or is this a non-issue?)

This last part of the question is important, may be this is a non-issue. Or do people do “something” (a few loops to get a deep clone)?

Comment: What doesn't work? What is this "This" in your question?

Comment: well "counterintuitive" is relative. For arrays most languages work this way. Otherwise you'd get a huge overhead. For Java Objects and Arrays the references are passed.  If you want a copy you'll need to create one.

Comment: @kai My question is if this is an issue (or may be not) and how is usually done the setting of a private attribute from a reference (do people deepcopy, or assume there won't be any problem outside)?

Comment: @jhamon I edited. I mean if this is usually how it's thone `this.foo = arr` or is it usually done with a deep copy?

Comment: @Manuel it is "usually" not done if not necessary. For the how to do a deep copy see the links in other comments(good explainations!).

Comment: @kai Yep, I know how to do a deepcopy, although I don't know if there's a general way of doing it for an array of n-dimension (or would I need to define such a method). But thanks, that was the answer I seeked.

Comment: @Manuel see 2nd comment from Spara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that java doesn't really have 2-D arrays. This:

```
int[][] x;
```

is an array of int arrays. It is *not* a 2D int array, though of course an array of int arrays does feel a lot like a 2D array. For most intents and purposes it iS a 2D int array, unless it isn't, and with clone, it isn't. The `clone()` impl of an array makes a new array and just copies each and every value, verbatim, into the new array. Which means that your array of int arrays is cloned, but the inner int arrays **are not**.

When treating `int[][]` as 'this is a 2D array', yeah, that is unintuitive. When treating `int[][]` as 'an array of int arrays', it is quite intuitive. You wouldn't expect an array of arraylists, when cloned, to also clone each individual arraylist either.

Soo.. how do you deep-clone an array of arrays (of arrays of arrays)? See [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java) for lots of options :)

Comment: The title of that linked question should be changed, since there are options to deep copy arrays of n-dimensions. Could you answer also if this is usually a non-issue, or how do people usually assign arrays to attributes?

Comment: Well, either [A] the array is small and you either deep-copy it around or more likely find a more palatable data type than arrays – a data type which is immutable, obviating the need for defensive copies. (The right datatype depends on what the array is representing. If it is representing a game board, perhaps make a class called Board. It has an int[][] internally, but you can't modify it, so you can pass around copies of Board at will). Alternatively, [B] it is a rather large array, in which case you really don't want to make defensive copies.