# Method is changing the value of the 2d array but I don't want it to

Tags: java

```
public static int[][] submatrix(int[][] arr, int i, int j)
{
    int[][] copyArr = arr;
    int[][] newArr = new int[copyArr.length - 1][copyArr[0].length - 1];
    
    for(int k = 0; k < copyArr[0].length; k++)
    {
        copyArr[j - 1][k] = 0;
    }
    
    for(int x = 0; x < copyArr.length; x++)
    {
        copyArr[x][i - 1] = 0;
    }
    printMatrix(copyArr);
    System.out.println();
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    
    for(int x = 0; x < copyArr.length; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < copyArr[0].length; y++)
        {
            if(copyArr[x][y] != 0)
            {
                newArr[row][col] = copyArr[x][y];
                col += 1;
                if(col == newArr[0].length)
                {
                    col -= newArr[0].length;
                    row += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

When I run this and use the 2d array:

int[][] matrixI = new int[][]{{11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {31, 32, 33, 34}, {41, 42, 43, 44}};

It correctly calculates the sub matrix, but when I call the method again on the same 2d array with different parameters(for the row and column I am getting rid of) it uses the array that was made when I called it the first time. I tried to use a copy of the array to avoid it changing the value of the inputted arr but it is still changing it.

The program is changing my value of arr when I dont want it to.

Comment: Don't you need nested for loops to adequately and deeply copy the 2D array? Or a single for loop and arraycopy calls?

Comment: Despite a copy being implied the line `int[][] copyArr = arr;` actually doesn't do a deep copy of `arr`. Both `copyArr` and `arr` are pointing to the same thing. So, any changes made to `copyArr` will change `arr`.  This question is possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Comment: Thank you, you were right about the copying confusion. I used a loop instead to iterate through and create a replica array and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a variable to another variable in Java doesn't create a copy. It creates a second reference to the same object, or array in this case. You need to use a method to actually create a copy if that is your intention: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-copy

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just assign `copyArr` to `arr` to make a legitimate copy.
Doing so will cause any updates within `arr` to also happen in `copyArr`.

*How that is useful, I'm not sure.*

You'll need to iterate over the values of `arr` and assign them to the corresponding indices of `copyArr`.

It's fairly simple, you can use the following code.

```java
int[][] copyArr = new int[arr.length][];
for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
    System.arraycopy(arr[i], 0, copyArr[i], 0, arr.length);
```